# Why doesn't MySQL allow auto_increment on VARCHAR columns?

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE patient(
   patient_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1000 AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

This statement does not work, and I do not understand why. Everywhere I see AUTO_INCREMENT only works with an integer. Why is it only for integers? What if I want a mix of INT and CHAR, and why doesn't the default value work?

Comment: Simply put, you **can't** auto increment a varchar or char. Your primary key fields must be numerical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoincrement a varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699591/how-to-autoincrement-a-varchar)

Answer (score 4):

> this query does not work

The error message is telling you why.  Simply put, you can't `auto_increment` character data.  What would you even expect that to do, really?

Even if it was implemented (which I imagine it *could* be, but the MySQL team never had a compelling reason to do so), what would you do with un-printable and un-typable characters in your primary key?  Imagine a record with the `BELL` character as the primary key.  That doesn't sound like fun.

> wherever I see auto_increment works with only int

Because only integers can meaningfully be incremented.  They have a very well defined step for each increment and a very well defined boundary of values.  Other data types don't.

> what if I want it to be char and int mix up

Wanting something doesn't make it happen.  Each column in a relational database has to have a defined type.  One column can't have more than one type.

> why default value does not work

Because you defined the column as character data, but defined the default as a numeric value.  The default for character data has to be a character value.

Comment: Exactly: `a`...`z`...??? You're right. Computers aren't powered by wishful thinking, though project managers often think programmers are.

Comment: "Wanting something doesn't make it happen."  Well put, sir!