# How to Auto-increment non-integer primary key in sql-server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am doing a project on asp.net. I have created a table where I want to auto increment the primary key. But the problem is the primary key is not an integer.

For example: In a table reqId is primary key. reqId of a row is suppose SB3001. If another row is inserted its reqID will be SB3002. How to auto-increment this?

Comment: have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699628/3953479

Comment: Use `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` for your PK and add the `SB` to it in the application.

Comment: @SB56 I have added my answer in duplicate question as per your requirement. Please check.